# Calling Java function within Javascript in JSP application

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I would like to access a variable and a set of functions from within a javascript segment. I have two files:

**testJSP.jsp**

```
<%@page import="test.tester"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            String thing = "Exciting String";
            tester testy = new tester(thing);
        %>
        <input type="submit" onclick="test()" value="Sample Text" />
        <div id="testDiv" >Boring String</div>
        <script language="javascript" >
            funciton test() {
                document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = <%=testy.getString()%>;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**tester.java**

```
package test;

public class tester {
    private String privy;

    public tester(String testString) {
        privy = testString;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return "new " + privy;
    }
}
```

Essentially, when the button is clicked, I want the element with id "testDiv" to be changed according to the function in the java file. I may be overlooking a very simple method, or perhaps there is a far more complex way of approaching this seemingly simple problem.

Comment: It's far more complex because the JavaScript code runs on the **client computer** while your Java code is trapped on your server. This is what AJAX is for.

Comment: @Pointy Im completely unfamiliar with Ajax. Rather than looking into that, would it be possible to store a string and pass it to another JSP page where it can then be modified before being displayed?

Comment: The key issue is that the software is running on computers separated by a network.

Comment: @CameronJewell as per ur code, it is all about client side ,if you want to change the value DIV , you will have to take a sever hit.  <%
            String thing = "Exciting String";
            tester testy = new tester(thing);
          String tst = test.getString();
        %>

<script language="javascript" >
            funciton test() {
                document.getElementById("testDiv").innerHTML = <%=tst%>;
            }
        </script>